# Validar qualquer input no mesmo momento

Tags: javascript

Eu estou fazendo uma validação ao vivo da entrada do campo CPF, mas não quero que deixe entrar letras e faça uma "mascara" de dados

```
cpf[0].onkeypress = function (e) {
var key = e.key
for(let i = 0 ; i <cpf[0].value.length ;i++) {
    if(cpf[0].value[i]==1 ||cpf[0].value[i]==2 ||cpf[0].value[i]==3 ||cpf[0].value[i]==4 ||cpf[0].value[i]==5 ||
        cpf[0].value[i]==6 ||cpf[0].value[i]==7 ||cpf[0].value[i]==8 ||cpf[0].value[i]==9 ||cpf[0].value[i]==10 ||
         cpf[0].value[i]=='.' || cpf[0].value[i]=='-') {

        } else {
            cpf[0].value="";
        }
}
if(key==1 ||key==2 ||key==3 ||key==4 ||key==5 ||
    key==6 ||key==7 ||key==8 ||key==9 ||key==10 ) {
    if(cpf[0].value.length==3){
        cpf[0].value+='.';
    } else if(cpf[0].value.length==7) {
        cpf[0].value+='.';
    } else if(cpf[0].value.length==11) {
        cpf[0].value+='-';
    }
} else {
    cpf[0].value="";
}
```

Porém acontece que quando a pessoa digita a letra ele limpa todo o campo do CPF e deixa a letra que a pessoa digitou, como que eu posso resolver isso?

Comment: Olá. Já tentou usar o onChange ao invés de onkeypress?

Answer (score 0):

Se você deseja apenas capatar os números do seu input, mude o type dele.

```
<input type="number" name="cpf">
```

Dessa forma seu input só poderá receber números.

Comment: Sim, mas eu queria fazer algo mais profissional colocando uma máscara de dados

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra opção seria utilizar um plugin em Jquery para aceitar apenas números e inserir pontos e traço. Aqui tem um exemplo:

https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Depois de baixar o plugin e copiar para a mesma pasta onde está o seu HTML, você pode utilizar da seguinte forma:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Mascara de CPF</title>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
  src="jQuery-Mask-Plugin-master/jQuery-Mask-Plugin-master/src/jquery.mask.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#CPF').mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
});
</script>  
<body>  
 <form>
  <label>CPF</label>
  <input type="text" name="CPF" id="CPF">
 </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/240354)

Comment: Obrigado por avisar. Já acrescentei um exemplo de como utilizar

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, irei testar aqui